# I want the VS 2022 (specifically VB) help files on my machine, so I don't have to have a connection

Tags: file, installation

I would like to have the help files local in Visual Basic 2022. How do I do that?

Larry

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/help-viewer/overview?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/help-viewer/overview?view=vs-2022

Deals specifically with Visual Studio Help Viewer and how to download and use it. (The tool allows you to store and view help content locally.) The latest version seems to be 2.3. I wonder if you have a versioning problem if it's offering you old material.  I installed it using Visual Studio 2022 using the Visual Studio Installer. (Tools|Get tools and features then searched for Help Viewer when the Visual Studio installer loaded.) Clicked Modify and it installed. Then back to Visual Studio and Help|Add and remove help content. The content list seemed up to date. Selected Visual Basic (no VB.NET in the list I saw but 3 MB as you say) and VS 2022 C++ (50 MB). Checked through the contents on Help Viewer - seemed OK to me and pretty complete.

Comment: Unfortunately the Help Content for download in the Help Viewer is a mess - I have VS2022 and it offers me documentation for VS2017 and even VS2015, it has duplicate docs for SQL Server 2019, and the section labelled "VB.NET" is listed as being only 3MB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).